# Importing Numpy array rows into __init__ function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, class, yfinance

I am attempting to create a class of options contracts, I would like to import each contract as an object with the attributes strikes, price, and volume. All this data is kept in a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker('COIN') 
dates = ticker.options
opt_chain = ticker.option_chain('2022-05-20')
opt_chain = np.asarray(opt_chain)



class Contract:
        def __init__(self,strike,price,volume):
            self.strike = strike
            self.price = price
            self.volume = volume
            pass
```

I'd like to import the strikes, price and volume of a singular contract (row) as an object in the contract class.
opt_chain prints like this

```
 0   COIN220520P00080000 2022-04-13 18:18:06+00:00    80.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 1   COIN220520P00085000 2022-04-13 19:57:49+00:00    85.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 2   COIN220520P00090000 2022-04-13 17:35:12+00:00    90.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 3   COIN220520P00095000 2022-04-13 19:35:08+00:00    95.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 4   COIN220520P00100000 2022-04-13 19:50:12+00:00   100.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 5   COIN220520P00105000 2022-04-13 17:37:39+00:00   105.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 6   COIN220520P00110000 2022-04-13 19:59:18+00:00   110.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 7   COIN220520P00115000 2022-04-13 19:59:18+00:00   115.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 8   COIN220520P00120000 2022-04-13 19:59:18+00:00   120.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 9   COIN220520P00125000 2022-04-13 19:59:18+00:00   125.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 10  COIN220520P00130000 2022-04-13 19:57:10+00:00   130.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 11  COIN220520P00135000 2022-04-13 18:19:02+00:00   135.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 12  COIN220520P00140000 2022-04-13 19:59:36+00:00   140.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 13  COIN220520P00145000 2022-04-13 19:56:12+00:00   145.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 14  COIN220520P00150000 2022-04-13 19:59:39+00:00   150.0  ...       False       REGULAR       USD
 15  COIN220520P00155000 2022-04-13 19:58:03+00:00   155.0  ...        True       REGULAR       USD
 16  COIN220520P00160000 2022-04-13 19:23:56+00:00   160.0  ...        True       REGULAR       USD
 17  COIN220520P00165000 2022-04-13 15:40:54+00:00   165.0  ...        True       REGULAR       USD
 18  COIN220520P00170000 2022-04-13 19:09:01+00:00   170.0  ...        True       REGULAR       USD
 19  COIN220520P00175000 2022-04-13 18:50:08+00:00   175.0  ...        True       REGULAR       USD
 20  COIN220520P00180000 2022-04-13 19:58:03+00:00   180.0  ...        True       REGULAR
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: the issue is that I do not know how to import each of those printed lines as objects. Id like the objects to only contain 3 pieces of information from each of those rows that is printed all of them are integers if that makes a difference. the print out is the print of opt_chain, the full numpy array, but I would like each row to be its own object.

Comment: Well, step back a moment.  What you have is a single array that stores all of your data, for easy analysis.  You're talking about separating this into a set of 20 objects, where each object has one row of that array.  Right?  That's going to make any bulk analysis much harder.  Are you sure that's a smart way to do it?  Do you really need to convert it to a numpy array in the first place?

Comment: @TimRoberts the first way I tried was to separate strikes, volume, and price into their own lists, and then tried to cut the lists down based on conditions that i wanted (ex. cutting the strikes list where strikes > 200 and then volume where volume is > 50 and so on.   The issue with that method was that I found it messy and confusing, trying to create a list of a few contracts that met my conditions for each list (strikes, price, volume).its about 56 rows total that I would like to analyze. Im fairly new to python and coding in general so I thought making them objects would be easier

Comment: `numpy` makes it easy to extract based on criteria.  Like `chain2 = chain1[chain1[:,3] <= 50]` keeps rows where column 3 is 50 or less.  That's a good reason to keep it intact.